# Memory management and removal of leaks, in C and Python with ctypes, using the example of strings

Tags: python, c, memory-management, memory-leaks, ctypes

I'm trying to fix leaks in a ctypes-based Python binding over a C library. I'm confused as to the behavior of memory management of strings and other pointers when working with ctypes.

There are, to my knowledge, 3 cases I need to solve, basically:

A) Creating memory in C and returning a `c_char_p` as the result of the function to the Python.

B) Creating a string in the Python, and passing it as a `char const*` parameter of a C function, and not freeing it in the C: this is the only one I've solved confidently: I can just do `my_str.encode("utf-8")` into a `c_char_p`, and the Python Alloc/GC handles both the allocation and deallocation.

C) Creating memory in Python, and storing it in the C (for example as a `char*` field within a struct), to be deallocated later (with a function from the C library).

My questions:

A)

- is the `c_char_p` thus created a second pointer ? If so, what happens to the pointer allocated by the C ?
- how do we free the pointer returned from the C ?
- is there a difference of behavior between how `c_void_p` and `c_char_p` are handled as `restype` by the GC ?

C)

- What is the correct way to "give ownership" of a memory pointer allocated in Python to the C ? `.encode()` clearly makes a Python object that's GC'ed.
- is a string created by `create_string_buffer` also Python-GC'ed ?

Answer (score 2):

The critical thing to realize with `ctypes.c_char_p` is `ctypes` has special handling for this return type where it copies the returned null-terminated byte string into a Python `bytes` object and returns that instead.  Access to the original pointer is lost as the return type actually received is a `bytes` object, not a pointer.  Note the same thing happens with `c_wchar_p` which is converted to a `str` object.

For `A)`, the solution is to use `ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char_p)` and the conversion won't occur, but can be done manually if needed.  The the return value can be passed back to a C function that deallocates the memory.

For `B)` you have the right idea.  Just pass a `bytes` object to C functions that take `const char*` and Python will manage the memory.  If the C function needs the object to be valid beyond the function call (perhaps for a later callback), be sure to keep a reference to the object until it is no longer needed.

For `C)` You can use either technique.  If C will manage the memory allocate in a C function, don't use `c_char_p` to obtain it, and free it in a C function; otherwise, use `create_string_buffer()` for Python to manage and keep a reference as long as needed by the C code.

Example of all techniques:

test.c

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define API __declspec(dllexport)

API char* funca() {
    char* p = malloc(6);
    strcpy_s(p, 6, "hello");
    return p;
}

API void funca_free(void* p) {
    *(char*)p = 'x'; // overwrite just to prove accessing a freed buffer
    free(p);         // that hasn't been re-used yet.
}

API void funcb(const char* p) {
    printf("B: %s\n", p);
}

static char* store = NULL;

API void funcc(char* p) {
    store = p;
}

API char* funcc_get() {
    return store;
}
```

test.py

```py
import ctypes as ct

dll = ct.CDLL('./test')
dll.funca.argtypes = ()
dll.funca.restype = ct.POINTER(ct.c_char) # NOT c_char_p, char* is lost
dll.funca_free.argtypes = ct.c_void_p,
dll.funca_free.restype = None
dll.funcb.argtypes = ct.c_char_p,
dll.funcb.restype = None
dll.funcc.argtypes = ct.c_char_p,
dll.funcc.restype = None
dll.funcc_get.argtypes = ()
dll.funcc_get.restype = ct.POINTER(ct.c_char) # NOT c_char_p

def funca_wrap():
    p = dll.funca() # C-managed
    s = ct.cast(p, ct.c_char_p).value # Make a copy as a Python byte string
    dll.funca_free(p) # Free by C as needed
    return s

print('A:', funca_wrap()) # Use a wrapper to capture string and free buffer

dll.funcb(b'input') # Python-managed and freed

s = ct.create_string_buffer(b'python') # Python-managed
dll.funcc(s)
p = dll.funcc_get()
print('C(py-alloc):', ct.cast(p,ct.c_char_p).value)
del s # Python-freed
print('C(py-freed):', ct.cast(p,ct.c_char_p).value) # access freed memory (could crash)

s = dll.funca() # C-managed (NOT c_char_p)
dll.funcc(s)
p = dll.funcc_get()
print('C(C-alloc):', ct.cast(p,ct.c_char_p).value)
dll.funca_free(s) # C-freed
print('C(C-freed):', ct.cast(p,ct.c_char_p).value) # access freed memory (could crash)
```

Output:

```
A: b'hello'
B: input
C(py-alloc): b'python'
C(py-freed): b'\x88\xc9?\xf1\x8a\x01'      # note freed memory reused in my case
C(C-alloc): b'hello'
C(C-freed): b'xello'                       # freed memory wasn't reused yet
```

Comment: Very helpful answer, thank you! I do have a question though: given the specificities of `c_char_p`, if I want to return a `char*`, by reference (by which I mean my C function is signed `int my_func(char* *address_of_result);` and called with `char* str = NULL; status = my_func(&str);`), how should I proceed with your scheme then ? Something like `POINTER(POINTER(c_char))`, or rather `POINTER(c_char_p)` ?

Comment: @TristanDuquesne The latter works.  Since you have to make `s = c_char_p()` and pass it by reference (e.g., byref(s)) to the function, you'll have the actual updated `c_char_p` object through `s` when the function returns, which can later be freed if needed.  `s.value` will return `char*` data as a `bytes` object.

Comment: What I gather is that `c_char_p` should never be used for anything that comes from the C, other than a string literal, since it'll generally lose the memory. Good to know in any case.

Comment: @TristanDuquesne If the value is a null-terminated string, and you don’t need to manage the pointer for C, use it; otherwise, don’t.

Answer (score 0):

This is an adaptation of the exchange I had on the Python discord server with someone who answered the questions:

- is the `c_char_p` thus created a second pointer ? If so, what happens to the pointer allocated by the C ?

Yes, it is. The `c_char_p` is a `PyObject*` pointer that lives on the heap, and it stores the original C `char*` pointer inside it.

- how do we free the pointer returned from the C ?

Pass the `c_char_p` to `free()` using `ctypes`

- is there a difference of behavior between how `c_void_p` and `c_char_p` are handled as restype by the GC ?

No, in both cases, when the `c_void_p` or `c_char_p` is garbage collected, it does nothing, ie, it does not free the original C object that was pointed to.

- What is the correct way to "give ownership" of a memory pointer allocated in Python to the C ?

That's not normally something you'd do - memory created by Python is usually freed by Python, memory created by C is usually freed by C. If you need to pass something from one domain to the other, it's best to copy it. It's possible to make the C side keep a Python reference to the Python object by using the Python C API, but that's probably not the best idea.

- is a string created by `create_string_buffer` also Python-GC'ed ?

In this case, when the Python object is GC'd, it also frees the C memory. A `c_char_p` knows whether it owns the memory that it points to or doesn't, and when it's GC'd it frees the C memory if it owns it.

========

Since my (I = asker) goal is to have as few (no) reference to ctypes types for the Python end-user, given the answers above, I would do the following:

- when I malloc a `char*` in the C in a function `char* do_c_func()`, I return it as a `c_char_p` restype in Python. In my Python, I have a wrapper function `do_py_func()` that calls `do_c_func()`, receives this `c_char_p` called `my_c_char_p`, and stores its contents in a Python string, through some sort of `s = str(my_c_char_p)`. I then call `ctypes.free(my_c_char_p)`: this frees the malloced `char*`, and the end of the function decrementing the last reference counter, this eventually garbage collects `my_c_char_p`.
- I create a conversion function `python_str_to_c_str(py_str)` which takes a normal python string, and returns `stdc.strdup(py_str.encode('utf-8'))` (with `stdc.strdup.restype = c_char_p`), thereby providing a new `char*` to the C (which Python will recognize as having been created in the C). I use this conversion function anywhere I need to pass a string from the Python to the C. This makes it so the buffer created by `my_string.encode('utf-8'))`, and the `c_char_p` returned by `stdc.strdup`, are both garbage-collected by the Python, but the `char*` itself is not.